# How to access dynamically loaded contents inside a shadowRoot of a Webcomponent from outside

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

Here user-select is a typeahead webcomponent that will load a list dynamically on typing.
What I am trying here is to  access the dynamically loaded userlist.

**On page load user-select is displayed with a text box (class="type-ahead-input").**

```
<user-select id="users">
 #shadow-root (open)
 <div id="web-component-root">
   <div class="type-ahead">
     <input aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Search for client" class="type-ahead-input">
   <div>
 </div>
</user-select>
```

**Once user starts typing, a list (class="type-ahead-result") is added dynamically and user is allowed to select.**

```
<user-select id="users">
 #shadow-root (open)
 <div id="web-component-root">
   <div class="type-ahead">
     <input aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Search for client" class="type-ahead-input">
     <div class="type-ahead-result">
       <div role="listbox" style="position:relative, height:1233px, width:100%, top:0, left:0">
          <div id="item-0">
               <li>
                   <span>Test0</span>
               </li>
           </div>
           <div id="item-1">
               <li>
                   <span>Test1</span>
               </li>
           </div>
           <div id="item-2">
               <li>
                   <span>Test2</span>
               </li>
           </div>
           -
           -
           -
           -
       </div>
     </div>
   <div>
 </div>
</user-select>
```

This is what I am trying.

```
let clientSelect = document.querySelector("user-select");
clientSelect.shadowRoot.querySelector('.type-ahead-result').addEventListener('click', ev => { 
  console.log(ev)
})
```

It seems as the list is dynamically addded to the shadow dom, the click event is not working.
Please let me know if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: There is a [< >] button on the StackOverflow toolbar, use it to convert your code in a working SO snippet.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I dont have access to the above webcomponent. I copied the  html from console and pasted here.

Comment: If you can't access the code, you can't fix it (well. maybe only with monkey patching). Report the issue with the Component author. You got something from IKEA, it doesn't work, return it to IKEA

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes, I have reported . But I was checking if there is a way that we can access the dynamic contents of a shadowRoot  from outside the component.

Comment: Your try is correct, ``document.querySelector("user-select").shadowRoot`` from the DEV console returns a DOM node if the shadowDOM was created with ``mode:"open"``; the fact it doesn't work says something more is happening.  If other code does ``preventDefault`` to cancel Events there isn't much you can do. If your Tesla breaks down you don't dive under the hood with a multimeter (well, I don't)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Need to check the webcomponent to see what;s happening.